# R: Nearest Neighbour Imputation for Non-NA possible?

Tags: r, replace, conditional-statements, nearest-neighbor, knn

I am having data like this:

```
v1 = c( -1, 1, 420, 400, 400, 170, 420) 
v2 = c( 350, 460, 420, 400, 500, 170, 420) 
v3 = c( 350, 460, 420, 1, 500, 3, 1) 
v4 = c( 1, NA, 420, 1, NA, 170, 420) 
v5 = c( 350, 400, 400, 1, 1, 3, 300) 
v6 = c( 350, 400, NA, 500, 500, 170, 300)
v7 = c(7,400,200,7,500,170,7)

DF1= data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7)
```

Resulting in a table/DF as follows:

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7
1   -1  350 350 1   350 350 7
2   1   460 460 NA  400 400 400
3   420 420 420 420 400 NA  200
4   400 400 1   1   1   500 7
5   400 500 500 NA  1   500 500
6   170 170 3   170 3   170 170
7   420 420 1   420 300 300 7
```

The 3 digit numbers are working hours (400=40h) and the one digits are states of employment. Problem with the data is, that I am aiming for monthly information (v1-v7 are months) but I have the working time surveyed just once a year. So I put it upon the states and now I have same blanks to fill.

I would like to replace the states "-1", "NA", "1" and "3" with the nearest neighbor (no calculation, just replacement of the next value higher than "50") giving priority to the value on the left/the variable left of the case that should be replaced.

At the end it should look like:

```
    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7
1   350 350 350 350 350 350 7
2   460 460 460 460 400 400 400
3   420 420 420 420 400 NA  200
4   400 400 400 400 500 500 7
5   400 500 500 500 500 500 500
6   170 170 170 170 170 170 170
7   420 420 420 420 300 300 7
```

Note line 4 where 2 of the "1" where the replaced with the value of the left and and one with the next value above 50 from the right - thats what I meant with "priority of the left".

So far I just had experience with the random impute of the impute-package and I have seen the knn-package, but to my understanding, it only works with NA, right?

I am grateful for any hint, because exporting it in .csv and resolve it manually would take me 10+ hours (11 datasets with 100-200 rows each)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is there an `NA` in your result (row 3)??

Comment: DF1["3","v6"] should be 400?

Comment: Also row 4 does not seem to follow your rules.

Comment: the NA in row 3 is a mistake of my design of this sample data... sorry... it should have been 400. - 

Row 4 is an example if there is more than 2 missings, the values should be take from one side and from the other (but giving a priority to the left side if the number of NA is uneven)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way, using `na.locf(...)` in package `zoo`.

```
# replace -1,1,3 with NA
DF1 <-  as.data.frame(sapply(DF1,function(x){x[x %in% c(-1,1,3)]<-NA;x}))
library(zoo)
# carry last obs forward into NAs, retaining NA at the beginnig of each row
result <- apply(DF1,1,na.locf,na.rm=FALSE)
result <- as.data.frame(t(apply(DF1,1,na.locf,fromLast=TRUE)))
result
#    v1  v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7
# 1 350 350 350 350 350 350   7
# 2 460 460 460 400 400 400 400
# 3 420 420 420 420 400 200 200
# 4 400 400 500 500 500 500   7
# 5 400 500 500 500 500 500 500
# 6 170 170 170 170 170 170 170
# 7 420 420 420 420 300 300   7
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about na.locf, but did not thought as far - for my understanding: the third row fills from the left and the fourth from the right, correct? As far I understand the "na.locf" is replacing one value at a time, so if i have for example 8 missing values I would have to perform the 3rd and 4th line of your code four times?

Comment: No. The code runs as is. `na.locf(...)` by default replaces all `NA`s with the last non-NA value. So `c(400,NA,NA,NA)` becomes `c(400,400,400,400)`. I suggest you read the documentation, and study the intermediate  results.